# Display multiple images in Python Tkinter Sequentially

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a program that displays an initial image, then shows the newest image in a folder.

I have everything working except the Tkinter panel displays the newest image below the first image in the window. I cannot figure out a way to destroy the original or to make another panel without the old image. I copied the relevant code below, not sure if it will execute error free. My .py file runs fine without any errors, just the unwanted results. Any help would be great.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import datetime
import sys, os

FILE_PATH = "C:\\easy\\Pics"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def quitX():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def prg_task():
    # code section removed....

    # continue code

    im = Image.open("C:\easy\imageNEW.jpg")

    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

    # get the image size
    w = image1.width()
    h = image1.height()+10

    # position coordinates of root 'upper left corner'
    x = 500
    y = 200

    # make the root window the size of the image
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

    # root has no image argument, so use a label as a panel
    panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
    panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both')

    # put a button on the image panel to test it
    button2 = Button(panel1, text='Close Window', command=quitX)
    button2.pack(side='bottom')

    # save the panel's image from 'garbage collection'
    panel1.image = image1

    root.after(10000, prg_task)

##########################################################################
# START CODE EXECUTION
# Initializing non-constant global variables

root = Tk()
root.title("Camera")
initIMG = Image.open("C:\easy\No-Image-Available.jpg")
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(initIMG)
panel1 = Label(root,image=tkimage)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both')
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# After 0.1s, attempt to grab still image from IP Camera
root.after(100, prg_task)
root.mainloop()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to show one image at a time you should create the panel and label only once. Each time you want to show a new image, create the image and then do somethign like `self.panel1.configure(image=new_image)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't using a class for the Tkinter frame so after your post I started working on a class. As of now most of it is working.